# Would there be homomorphism?

Tags: ring-homomorphism

$H=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}:a,b,c\in Z\right\}$ get the ring $\varphi :H\rightarrow Z$ , $\varphi \left( \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}\right) =c$ Does the transformation become a ring homomorphism? 
Essays:
$\varphi \left( \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} d & e \\ 0 & f \end{bmatrix}\right)=\varphi \left( \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ o & c \end{bmatrix}\right) +\varphi \left( \begin{bmatrix} d & e \\ 0 & f \end{bmatrix}\right)$ because $c\neq 2c$ there is no homomorphism with interest, right?  Is there something I can't see?

Comment: $fi(A+B)=c+f=fi(A)+fi(B)$

Comment: When you write $\varphi \left( \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}\right) =c$, the $c$ in the RHS is the same $c$ as in the LHS.

Comment: @Gae.S. I do not understand

Comment: @YusufKanat I figured as much.

Comment: can you solve it?

Comment: where does $2c$ come from $? c\ne 2c$

Comment: You get $c+f$ on both sides. Where does this $2c$ come from?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah $\varphi \left( \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ o & c \end{bmatrix}\right) +\varphi \left( \begin{bmatrix} d & e \\ 0 & f \end{bmatrix}\right)=2c$

Comment: if you solve it i will be very pleased my english is not very good.

Comment: Why do you think $\varphi \left( \begin{bmatrix} d & e \\ 0 & f \end{bmatrix}\right)=c$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber the conversion was given that way

Comment: @NoahSchweber you perfect man!!